# Mysqli dump of Countries with latitude and longitude

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, latitude-longitude

Where can i find all countries with latitude and longitude mysqli dump. i couldn't find a table only with countries and latitude longitude.

Comment: You can get csv format of list of countries and lat long here: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/codes/country_latlon/

Comment: you can get countries with lattitude and longitude here : https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv

Comment: well could not find download link there on developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you wrote in comment - "*..well could not find download link there
>   on [countries.csv](https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv)* "

If you are not able to find latitude and longitude anywhere. Then, create country's `latitude` and `longitude` by own. Why to spend time on searching.

**Option-1:**

Let us say :

**Table** : `country`

**Column** : `country_id`, `country`, `latitude`, `longitude`.

```
<?

//$conn as connection name.

$query = "SELECT country_id, country FROM country";
$countryQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($countryQuery))
{
    $country = $row['country'];
    $country_id = $row['country_id'];

    $geo = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode($country) . '&sensor=false');
    $geo = json_decode($geo, true);
    if ($geo['status'] == 'OK') {
        $latitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
        $longitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
        $QueryLonLat = "UPDATE country SET latitude='$latitude', longitude ='$longitude' WHERE country_id='$country_id'";
        mysqli_query($conn, $QueryLonLat);
    }
}
```

*One Hit on this page and you will get all what you want.*

> **Gautam Buddha** Says : "*No one saves us but ourselves. No one can and no one may. We ourselves must walk the path.*"

**Option-2:** For The Lazy One's Out There..

Create Table `apps_countries`

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `apps_countries` (   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `country_code` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   `country_name`
>   varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',   `latitude` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
>   `longitude` varchar(25) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=235
>   DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> ALTER TABLE `apps_countries` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`); ALTER TABLE
>   `apps_countries` MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=235;

Dumping data for table `apps_countries`

> INSERT INTO `apps_countries` (`id`, `country_code`, `country_name`,
>   `latitude`, `longitude`) VALUES (1, 'AF', 'Afghanistan', '33.93911',
>   '67.709953'), (2, 'AL', 'Albania', '41.153332', '20.168331'), (3,
>   'DZ', 'Algeria', '28.033886', '1.659626'), (4, 'DS', 'American Samoa',
>   '', ''), (5, 'AD', 'Andorra', '', ''), (6, 'AO', 'Angola',
>   '-11.202692', '17.873887'), (7, 'AI', 'Anguilla', '18.220554',
>   '-63.068615'), (8, 'AQ', 'Antarctica', '-82.8627519', '135'), (9,
>   'AG', 'Antigua and Barbuda', '17.060816', '-61.796428'), (10, 'AR',
>   'Argentina', '-38.416097', '-63.616672'), (11, 'AM', 'Armenia', '',
>   ''), (12, 'AW', 'Aruba', '12.52111', '-69.968338'), (13, 'AU',
>   'Australia', '-25.274398', '133.775136'), (14, 'AT', 'Austria',
>   '47.516231', '14.550072'), (15, 'AZ', 'Azerbaijan', '40.143105',
>   '47.576927'), (16, 'BS', 'Bahamas', '25.03428', '-77.39628'), (17,
>   'BH', 'Bahrain', '', ''), (18, 'BD', 'Bangladesh', '', ''), (19, 'BB',
>   'Barbados', '13.193887', '-59.543198'), (20, 'BY', 'Belarus',
>   '53.709807', '27.953389'), (21, 'BE', 'Belgium', '50.503887',
>   '4.469936'), (22, 'BZ', 'Belize', '17.189877', '-88.49765'), (23,
>   'BJ', 'Benin', '9.30769', '2.315834'), (24, 'BM', 'Bermuda', '', ''),
>   (25, 'BT', 'Bhutan', '', ''), (26, 'BO', 'Bolivia', '', ''), (27,
>   'BA', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', '', ''), (28, 'BW', 'Botswana', '',
>   ''), (29, 'BV', 'Bouvet Island', '-54.423199', '3.413194'), (30, 'BR',
>   'Brazil', '-14.235004', '-51.92528'), (31, 'IO', 'British Indian Ocean
>   Territory', '-7.3346232', '72.4242508'), (32, 'BN', 'Brunei
>   Darussalam', '4.535277', '114.727669'), (33, 'BG', 'Bulgaria',
>   '42.733883', '25.48583'), (34, 'BF', 'Burkina Faso', '12.238333',
>   '-1.561593'), (35, 'BI', 'Burundi', '-3.373056', '29.918886'), (36,
>   'KH', 'Cambodia', '12.565679', '104.990963'), (37, 'CM', 'Cameroon',
>   '7.369722', '12.354722'), (38, 'CA', 'Canada', '56.130366',
>   '-106.346771'), (39, 'CV', 'Cape Verde', '', ''), (40, 'KY', 'Cayman
>   Islands', '', ''), (41, 'CF', 'Central African Republic', '6.611111',
>   '20.939444'), (42, 'TD', 'Chad', '15.454166', '18.732207'), (43, 'CL',
>   'Chile', '-35.675147', '-71.542969'), (44, 'CN', 'China', '35.86166',
>   '104.195397'), (45, 'CX', 'Christmas Island', '-10.447525',
>   '105.690449'), (46, 'CC', 'Cocos (Keeling) Islands', '', ''), (47,
>   'CO', 'Colombia', '', ''), (48, 'KM', 'Comoros', '-11.6455',
>   '43.3333'), (49, 'CG', 'Congo', '-0.228021', '15.827659'), (50, 'CK',
>   'Cook Islands', '-21.236736', '-159.777671'), (51, 'CR', 'Costa Rica',
>   '9.748917', '-83.753428'), (52, 'HR', 'Croatia (Hrvatska)', '45.1',
>   '15.2'), (53, 'CU', 'Cuba', '21.521757', '-77.781167'), (54, 'CY',
>   'Cyprus', '35.126413', '33.429859'), (55, 'CZ', 'Czech Republic',
>   '49.817492', '15.472962'), (56, 'DK', 'Denmark', '56.26392',
>   '9.501785'), (57, 'DJ', 'Djibouti', '11.825138', '42.590275'), (58,
>   'DM', 'Dominica', '15.414999', '-61.370976'), (59, 'DO', 'Dominican
>   Republic', '18.735693', '-70.162651'), (60, 'TP', 'East Timor',
>   '-8.874217', '125.727539'), (61, 'EC', 'Ecuador', '', ''), (62, 'EG',
>   'Egypt', '26.820553', '30.802498'), (63, 'SV', 'El Salvador',
>   '13.794185', '-88.89653'), (64, 'GQ', 'Equatorial Guinea', '1.650801',
>   '10.267895'), (65, 'ER', 'Eritrea', '15.179384', '39.782334'), (66,
>   'EE', 'Estonia', '58.595272', '25.013607'), (67, 'ET', 'Ethiopia',
>   '9.145', '40.489673'), (68, 'FK', 'Falkland Islands (Malvinas)',
>   '-51.796253', '-59.523613'), (69, 'FO', 'Faroe Islands', '61.892635',
>   '-6.911806'), (70, 'FJ', 'Fiji', '-17.713371', '178.065032'), (71,
>   'FI', 'Finland', '61.92411', '25.748151'), (72, 'FR', 'France',
>   '46.227638', '2.213749'), (73, 'FX', 'France, Metropolitan',
>   '14.4811297', '121.0304117'), (74, 'GF', 'French Guiana', '3.933889',
>   '-53.125782'), (75, 'PF', 'French Polynesia', '-17.679742',
>   '-149.406843'), (76, 'TF', 'French Southern Territories',
>   '-49.280366', '69.348557'), (77, 'GA', 'Gabon', '-0.803689',
>   '11.609444'), (78, 'GM', 'Gambia', '13.443182', '-15.310139'), (79,
>   'GE', 'Georgia', '32.1656221', '-82.9000751'), (80, 'DE', 'Germany',
>   '51.165691', '10.451526'), (81, 'GH', 'Ghana', '7.946527',
>   '-1.023194'), (82, 'GI', 'Gibraltar', '36.140751', '-5.353585'), (83,
>   'GK', 'Guernsey', '49.465691', '-2.585278'), (84, 'GR', 'Greece',
>   '39.074208', '21.824312'), (85, 'GL', 'Greenland', '71.706936',
>   '-42.604303'), (86, 'GD', 'Grenada', '12.1165', '-61.679'), (87, 'GP',
>   'Guadeloupe', '16.265', '-61.551'), (88, 'GU', 'Guam', '13.444304',
>   '144.793731'), (89, 'GT', 'Guatemala', '15.783471', '-90.230759'),
>   (90, 'GN', 'Guinea', '9.945587', '-9.696645'), (91, 'GW',
>   'Guinea-Bissau', '11.803749', '-15.180413'), (92, 'GY', 'Guyana',
>   '4.860416', '-58.93018'), (93, 'HT', 'Haiti', '18.971187',
>   '-72.285215'), (94, 'HM', 'Heard and Mc Donald Islands', '-53.1',
>   '73.5'), (95, 'HN', 'Honduras', '15.199999', '-86.241905'), (96, 'HK',
>   'Hong Kong', '22.396428', '114.109497'), (97, 'HU', 'Hungary',
>   '47.162494', '19.503304'), (98, 'IS', 'Iceland', '64.963051',
>   '-19.020835'), (99, 'IN', 'India', '20.593684', '78.96288'), (100,
>   'IM', 'Isle of Man', '54.236107', '-4.548056'), (101, 'ID',
>   'Indonesia', '-0.789275', '113.921327'), (102, 'IR', 'Iran (Islamic
>   Republic of)', '38.4703541', '47.0571193'), (103, 'IQ', 'Iraq',
>   '33.223191', '43.679291'), (104, 'IE', 'Ireland', '53.41291',
>   '-8.24389'), (105, 'IL', 'Israel', '31.046051', '34.851612'), (106,
>   'IT', 'Italy', '41.87194', '12.56738'), (107, 'CI', 'Ivory Coast',
>   '7.539989', '-5.54708'), (108, 'JE', 'Jersey', '49.214439',
>   '-2.13125'), (109, 'JM', 'Jamaica', '18.109581', '-77.297508'), (110,
>   'JP', 'Japan', '36.204824', '138.252924'), (111, 'JO', 'Jordan',
>   '30.585164', '36.238414'), (112, 'KZ', 'Kazakhstan', '48.019573',
>   '66.923684'), (113, 'KE', 'Kenya', '-0.023559', '37.906193'), (114,
>   'KI', 'Kiribati', '1.8708833', '-157.3630262'), (115, 'KP', 'Korea,
>   Democratic People''s Republic of', '', ''), (116, 'KR', 'Korea,
>   Republic of', '24.4975048', '118.1257661'), (117, 'XK', 'Kosovo',
>   '42.6026359', '20.902977'), (118, 'KW', 'Kuwait', '29.31166',
>   '47.481766'), (119, 'KG', 'Kyrgyzstan', '41.20438', '74.766098'),
>   (120, 'LA', 'Lao People''s Democratic Republic', '19.85627',
>   '102.495496'), (121, 'LV', 'Latvia', '56.879635', '24.603189'), (122,
>   'LB', 'Lebanon', '33.854721', '35.862285'), (123, 'LS', 'Lesotho',
>   '-29.609988', '28.233608'), (124, 'LR', 'Liberia', '6.428055',
>   '-9.429499'), (125, 'LY', 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya', '26.3351',
>   '17.228331'), (126, 'LI', 'Liechtenstein', '47.166', '9.555373'),
>   (127, 'LT', 'Lithuania', '55.169438', '23.881275'), (128, 'LU',
>   'Luxembourg', '49.815273', '6.129583'), (129, 'MO', 'Macau',
>   '22.198745', '113.543873'), (130, 'MK', 'Macedonia', '41.608635',
>   '21.745275'), (131, 'MG', 'Madagascar', '-18.766947', '46.869107'),
>   (132, 'MW', 'Malawi', '-13.254308', '34.301525'), (133, 'MY',
>   'Malaysia', '4.210484', '101.975766'), (134, 'MV', 'Maldives',
>   '1.977247', '73.5361034'), (135, 'ML', 'Mali', '17.570692',
>   '-3.996166'), (136, 'MT', 'Malta', '35.937496', '14.375416'), (137,
>   'MH', 'Marshall Islands', '6.0683017', '171.989379'), (138, 'MQ',
>   'Martinique', '14.641528', '-61.024174'), (139, 'MR', 'Mauritania',
>   '21.00789', '-10.940835'), (140, 'MU', 'Mauritius', '-20.348404',
>   '57.552152'), (141, 'TY', 'Mayotte', '-12.8275', '45.166244'), (142,
>   'MX', 'Mexico', '23.634501', '-102.552784'), (143, 'FM', 'Micronesia,
>   Federated States of', '', ''), (144, 'MD', 'Moldova, Republic of',
>   '46.9821667', '28.8365339'), (145, 'MC', 'Monaco', '43.7384176',
>   '7.4246158'), (146, 'MN', 'Mongolia', '46.862496', '103.846656'),
>   (147, 'ME', 'Montenegro', '42.708678', '19.37439'), (148, 'MS',
>   'Montserrat', '16.742498', '-62.187366'), (149, 'MA', 'Morocco',
>   '31.791702', '-7.09262'), (150, 'MZ', 'Mozambique', '-18.665695',
>   '35.529562'), (151, 'MM', 'Myanmar', '21.916221', '95.955974'), (152,
>   'NA', 'Namibia', '-22.95764', '18.49041'), (153, 'NR', 'Nauru',
>   '-0.522778', '166.931503'), (154, 'NP', 'Nepal', '28.394857',
>   '84.124008'), (155, 'NL', 'Netherlands', '52.132633', '5.291266'),
>   (156, 'AN', 'Netherlands Antilles', '12.2018902', '-68.2623822'),
>   (157, 'NC', 'New Caledonia', '-20.904305', '165.618042'), (158, 'NZ',
>   'New Zealand', '-40.900557', '174.885971'), (159, 'NI', 'Nicaragua',
>   '12.865416', '-85.207229'), (160, 'NE', 'Niger', '17.607789',
>   '8.081666'), (161, 'NG', 'Nigeria', '9.081999', '8.675277'), (162,
>   'NU', 'Niue', '-19.054445', '-169.867233'), (163, 'NF', 'Norfolk
>   Island', '-29.040835', '167.954712'), (164, 'MP', 'Northern Mariana
>   Islands', '15.0979', '145.6739'), (165, 'NO', 'Norway', '60.472024',
>   '8.468946'), (166, 'OM', 'Oman', '21.512583', '55.923255'), (167,
>   'PK', 'Pakistan', '30.375321', '69.345116'), (168, 'PW', 'Palau',
>   '7.51498', '134.58252'), (169, 'PS', 'Palestine', '31.952162',
>   '35.233154'), (170, 'PA', 'Panama', '8.537981', '-80.782127'), (171,
>   'PG', 'Papua New Guinea', '-6.314993', '143.95555'), (172, 'PY',
>   'Paraguay', '-23.442503', '-58.443832'), (173, 'PE', 'Peru',
>   '-9.189967', '-75.015152'), (174, 'PH', 'Philippines', '12.879721',
>   '121.774017'), (175, 'PN', 'Pitcairn', '-24.3767452', '-128.3242353'),
>   (176, 'PL', 'Poland', '51.919438', '19.145136'), (177, 'PT',
>   'Portugal', '39.399872', '-8.224454'), (178, 'PR', 'Puerto Rico',
>   '18.220833', '-66.590149'), (179, 'QA', 'Qatar', '25.354826',
>   '51.183884'), (180, 'RE', 'Reunion', '-21.115141', '55.536384'), (181,
>   'RO', 'Romania', '45.943161', '24.96676'), (182, 'RU', 'Russian
>   Federation', '61.52401', '105.318756'), (183, 'RW', 'Rwanda',
>   '-1.940278', '29.873888'), (184, 'KN', 'Saint Kitts and Nevis',
>   '17.357822', '-62.782998'), (185, 'LC', 'Saint Lucia', '13.909444',
>   '-60.978893'), (186, 'VC', 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines',
>   '13.2528179', '-61.1971628'), (187, 'WS', 'Samoa', '-13.759029',
>   '-172.104629'), (188, 'SM', 'San Marino', '43.94236', '12.457777'),
>   (189, 'ST', 'Sao Tome and Principe', '0.18636', '6.613081'), (190,
>   'SA', 'Saudi Arabia', '23.885942', '45.079162'), (191, 'SN',
>   'Senegal', '14.497401', '-14.452362'), (192, 'RS', 'Serbia',
>   '44.016521', '21.005859'), (193, 'SC', 'Seychelles', '-4.679574',
>   '55.491977'), (194, 'SL', 'Sierra Leone', '8.460555', '-11.779889'),
>   (195, 'SG', 'Singapore', '1.352083', '103.819836'), (196, 'SK',
>   'Slovakia', '48.669026', '19.699024'), (197, 'SI', 'Slovenia',
>   '46.151241', '14.995463'), (198, 'SB', 'Solomon Islands', '-9.64571',
>   '160.156194'), (199, 'SO', 'Somalia', '5.152149', '46.199616'), (200,
>   'ZA', 'South Africa', '-30.559482', '22.937506'), (201, 'GS', 'South
>   Georgia South Sandwich Islands', '', ''), (202, 'ES', 'Spain',
>   '40.463667', '-3.74922'), (203, 'LK', 'Sri Lanka', '7.873054',
>   '80.771797'), (204, 'SH', 'St. Helena', '38.5052429', '-122.4703868'),
>   (205, 'PM', 'St. Pierre and Miquelon', '46.8852', '-56.3159'), (206,
>   'SD', 'Sudan', '12.862807', '30.217636'), (207, 'SR', 'Suriname',
>   '3.919305', '-56.027783'), (208, 'SJ', 'Svalbard and Jan Mayen
>   Islands', '71.031818', '-8.2920347'), (209, 'SZ', 'Swaziland',
>   '-26.522503', '31.465866'), (210, 'SE', 'Sweden', '60.128161',
>   '18.643501'), (211, 'CH', 'Switzerland', '46.818188', '8.227512'),
>   (212, 'SY', 'Syrian Arab Republic', '34.802075', '38.996815'), (213,
>   'TW', 'Taiwan', '23.69781', '120.960515'), (214, 'TJ', 'Tajikistan',
>   '38.861034', '71.276093'), (215, 'TZ', 'Tanzania, United Republic of',
>   '', ''), (216, 'TH', 'Thailand', '15.870032', '100.992541'), (217,
>   'TG', 'Togo', '8.619543', '0.824782'), (218, 'TK', 'Tokelau',
>   '-9.2002', '-171.8484'), (219, 'TO', 'Tonga', '-21.178986',
>   '-175.198242'), (220, 'TT', 'Trinidad and Tobago', '10.691803',
>   '-61.222503'), (221, 'TN', 'Tunisia', '33.886917', '9.537499'), (222,
>   'TR', 'Turkey', '38.963745', '35.243322'), (223, 'TM', 'Turkmenistan',
>   '38.969719', '59.556278'), (224, 'TC', 'Turks and Caicos Islands',
>   '21.694025', '-71.797928'), (225, 'TV', 'Tuvalu', '-7.4784206',
>   '178.679924'), (226, 'UG', 'Uganda', '1.373333', '32.290275'), (227,
>   'UA', 'Ukraine', '48.379433', '31.16558'), (228, 'AE', 'United Arab
>   Emirates', '23.424076', '53.847818'), (229, 'GB', 'United Kingdom',
>   '55.378051', '-3.435973'), (230, 'US', 'United States', '37.09024',
>   '-95.712891'), (231, 'UM', 'United States minor outlying islands',
>   '19.2823192', '166.647047'), (232, 'UY', 'Uruguay', '-32.522779',
>   '-55.765835'), (233, 'UZ', 'Uzbekistan', '41.377491', '64.585262'),
>   (234, 'VU', 'Vanuatu', '-15.376706', '166.959158');

Comment: Thank you for your help.